# Printing out values of different rows and column in 2d array using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have this 2d array of the first row being first names and the second being last names.

```java
String[][] ladrones2 = {
        {"Phil", "Kim", "Phil", "Perry"},
        {"Garcia", "Gimena", "Basinger", "Ornitorrinco"}};
```

the prefered out come of this would be to have them printend out like e.g

```
Phill Garcia
Kim Gimena
etc...
```

Now I was able to do this by catching the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception and it works and the output is:

```
name Phil Garcia
name Kim Gimena
name Phil Basinger
name Perry Ornitorrinco
```

Which is great but I wondered if there was a way to do this without having to catch the exception? I've been searching to make this cleaner but wasn't able to do so.

Code at the moment:

```java
public static void robo2() {
    String[][] ladrones2 = {
            {"Phil", "Kim", "Phil", "Perry"},
            {"Garcia", "Gimena", "Basinger", "Ornitorrinco"}};

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < ladrones2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ladrones2[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println("name: " + ladrones2[i][j] + " " + ladrones2[i + 1][j]);
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

as you can see I used in the inner for loop a `+1` on the `i` variable which in turn throws the exception.

Any ideas? I would like just to keep this way of working at the moment with 2 forloops due to being new to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that `ladrones2` array always has 2 rows, then below code would be simpler:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] ladrones2 = {
            {"Phil", "Kim", "Phil", "Perry"},
            {"Garcia", "Gimena", "Basinger", "Ornitorrinco"}};

    for (int i = 0; i < ladrones2[0].length; i++) {
        System.out.println("name: " + ladrones2[0][i] + " " + ladrones2[1][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sundhir , nice I got the same output thanks for the advice. 
I just have one more question I don't seem to understand here. Why are we still putting [0] after ladrones2 in the for loop? Wouldn't that not be used only on the inner for loop if you would use one ? Thanks for the help already.

Comment: @SamuelVanBladel `[0]` gives name count in each row. This is required to stop the loop once all names are printed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sudhir, thanks for the quick reply but what do you mean with "name count" ?

Comment: @SamuelVanBladel "name count" - number of elements (names) in each row of the 2d array

Answer (score 1):

On this line :

```
System.out.println("name: " + ladrones2[i][j] + " " + ladrones2[i + 1][j]);
```

You are taking an element from the first and second array at the same time but you are looping over all the elements in the sequence on this line :

```
for (int i = 0; i < ladrones2.length; i++)
```

To correct this problem, you simply have to reduce the range of `i` to `ladrones.length-1`, otherwise you will reach the end of the array and try to access the next element which doesn't exist here.

You'll end up with this line instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < ladrones2.length-1; i++) {
```

Comment: Hi Simon, I've added the -1 to my outer for loop but now I get the following output. 

`name: Phil Garcia
name: Kim Garcia
name: Phil Garcia
name: Perry Garcia`

As yiu can see the second row gets stuck on 1 - 0

Comment: You probably did something wrong here. If you followed my advices, you should have written the following code :

```Java
for (int i = 0; i < ladrones2.length-1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ladrones2[i].length; j++) {System.out.println("name: " + ladrones2[i][j] + " " + ladrones2[i + 1][j]);
   }
  }
```